# What does the syntax in this two expression for loop mean?

Tags: javascript

What do the two expressions `var i = 0, item; item = a[i++];` mean?

```
for (var i = 0, item; item = a[i++];) {  
    // Do something with item  
}
```

Apparently this is an alternative to

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {  
    // Do something with a[i]  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0, item; item = a[i++];) {  
    // Do something with item  
}
```

Is telling the loop to keep going so long as `item` gets assigned a "truthy" value.  After each iteration, `item` is assigned the next item in the array.  The idea is that once `i` gets to a point where it's beyond the bounds of the array, `undefined` will be assigned, and the loop will terminate.

<strike>But whoever wrote this code should be fired since the loop will also terminate if the array contains any "falsy" values: 0, empty string, false</strike> Ok, this code was written by the Mozilla folks, and they're much smarter than I am.  Just note that the loop will terminate if the array contains any "falsy" values: `0`, `empty string`, `false`

To see for yourself:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6];

for (var i = 0, item; item = a[i++]; ) {
    alert(item);
}
```

note that the loop terminates after 3, since 0 is falsy.

Comment: Damn you, why are you so fast? :)

Comment: I dunno, arrays are supposed to contains values of same types. In this case most likely objects - having falsy values mixed with objects in an array is bigger fail. :P

Comment: Thanks Adam, I got this code in the middle of this tutorial from mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Comment: @Esailija - I guess if you can gaurentee that the array will only contain objects, and not strings or numbers, then sure, this is safe—or were you just joking :)

Comment: But why the var i=0, item?  That assigns i=0 then evaluates to item (whatever that is).  How does that play out as the initializer for the loop?  Sheesh - too clever by half. UPDATE: Never mind, followed the link.  It declares the variable item, but doesn't initialize it.

Comment: @schtever - i is being used to index the array.  That's why it starts out as 0, and after each iteration, item gets assigns a[i++].  That returns a[i] and then increments i (i++ is the post-increment operator)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - my day job is too easy :)

Comment: @AdamRackis no I wasn't, it doesn't really make sense to use an array of mixed types. I.E. `[0,1,3,{},"ok"]`.

Comment: @Esailija - I agree.  I'm just saying that this particular idiom won't work with certain types.  You couldn't do this with an array of numbers since a zero entry would kill the loop, or an array of strings, since empty string...

Comment: Yep but I wrote it when you said to fire the guy :D I wanted to imply that you should give the guy a benefit of doubt, that the array is in fact an array of objects that can never evaluate to false, unless an even bigger fail is exercised: using an array to store `all the things`

Comment: @Esailija - that wasn't exactly my best moment :-)